# Inheritance & singleton not working as desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Having that project config:

```
- src/
   |-- classes/
      |-- Logger.py
      |-- Browser.py
   |-- ubigeo.py
- main.py
```

I'm trying to use `python-logstash-logger` setting up in `Logger.py` class to print logs in `Browser.py` class, `ubigeo.py` and `main.py` scripts:

```
#Logger.py
import logging, logstash

class LoggerSingleton:
  _shared_state = {}

  def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__ = self._shared_state

class Logger(LoggerSingleton):
  def __init__(self):
    LoggerSingleton.__init__(self)
    self.logger = self.init_console_logger()

  def init_console_logger(self):
    logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
    logger.setLevel('DEBUG')

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')

    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    sh.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(sh)

    return logger

  def log(self, message):
    self.logger.info(message)
```

The main problem is that when I have multiple instances of the same class, the log print multiple times.

```
#main.py
from src.classes import Logger

if __name__ == "__main__":
  logger_handler = Logger()
  logger_handler.log('Checking python version...')

  ubigeo.main()
```

```
#Browser.py
from .Logger import Logger

class Browser(Config, Logger):
  def __init__(self):
    self.logger = Logger()
    self.logger.log('Setting up & launching a browser')
```

```
#ubigeo.py
from .classes.Browser import Browser

def main():
  browser_handler = Browser()
```

The log result of this right now is:

```
2019-04-21 13:25:12,758 : INFO : Checking python version...
2019-04-21 13:25:12,915 : INFO : Setting up & launching a browser
2019-04-21 13:25:12,915 : INFO : Setting up & launching a browser
```

and the desired result is

```
2019-04-21 13:25:12,758 : INFO : Checking python version...
2019-04-21 13:25:12,915 : INFO : Setting up & launching a browser
```

Comment: Your definition of class Browser is invalid in the given listing. it uses 'self' outside of any method context, which wouldn't work.

Comment: I just updated my code since I copied bad the piece I wanted to show

Comment: Your Browser both is a Logger (because it inherits from Logger), and has a Logger, (because you define self.logger).  It shouldn't do both.  Why not stick to the established patterns for logging, where the app main configures logging?

Comment: You get multiple messages because you are calling Logger() once every time you create a Browser() object.  Logger() calls addHandler() each time, so you have multiple handlers.

Comment: One more bit of (unasked-for) advice: don't use "import src.classes.whatever": src and classes are useless names for your directories.  All of your code is source, and most of your code will be classes.

Comment: I was trying to simply `self.logger.info` instead of `self.logger = Logger() and self.logger.info('message)` because of inheritance, but it seems it's not working. Following your tip about established patterns for logging, is it just better to instantiate once in the app main and just inject the instance to the class?

Comment: Usually, people use a module-global logger, but passing one to an object could also work.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your answer and your advices. It helped me coding the right way @NedBatchelder